# How to stop a VPN server launched with vpnd

Tags: vpn

I have a home VPN set up (OS X's native L2TP/IPsec on a 10.13 machine). I appreciate that the recommended way to start this would be via launchctl but, accepting that I invoked vpnd directly:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/vpnd -d -i com.apple.ppp.l2tp
```

What command would stop the server? The man page for vpnd does not provide information on how to halt the server.

Answer (score 1):

Two Ways to Kill a Process (sung to the tune of ["Fifty Ways to Leave Your Lover"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABXtWqmArUU))

First Way:

> 1. Launch `Activity Monitor`
> 2. Locate the daemon/process you want to halt (`vpnd` in this case), and select it (white letters on blue field)
> 3. Click the `x` button in the ULHC, `Force a process to quit`
> 4. Confirm by clicking `Quit`, or `Force Quit` if it's stubborn :)

Second Way:
If you're keen on the command line, why not use `kill`? see `man kill`

> 1. Get the PID for your daemon `vpnd`: `ps -ax | grep vpnd`,
> 2. `kill PID` (where PID of course is the actual PID number)